# Context Query in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project in which I am trying to hold customer information in CustomerContext which will then be passed down to every component in the hierarchy. Here's how I am trying to achieve this,

Context.js

```
export const CustomerContext = createContext();
```

**CustomerContext.Provider** in App.js

```
 const App = () => {
  const [ customerInfo, setCustomerInfo ] = useState();
  return (
    <CustomerContext.Provider value={{customerInfo, setCustomerInfo}}>
      <CategoryContext.Provider value={{categoryList, setCategoryList}} >
        <CartContext.Provider value={{cartData, setCartData}}>
          <Router>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
            ...
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
          </Router>
        </CartContext.Provider>
      </CategoryContext.Provider>
    </CustomerContext.Provider> 
   )
}
```

Login.js

```
   ...
       const { customerInfo } = useContext(CustomerContext);

   ...
   ...
   const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', usernameRef.current.value);
        formData.append('password', pwdRef.current.value);
        axios.post(loginUrlRef.current, formData)
            .then((response) => {
                ...
                handleCustomerLoggedIn(customerContext, response.data.user, response.data.id);
                ...
```

CustomerUtils.js

```
export const handleCustomerLoggedIn = (customerContext, username, customerId) => {
    console.log(`${TAG} handleCustomerLoggedIn: ${username}, ${customerId}`);
    customerContext.setCustomerInfo({
        login: true,
        customer_id: customerId,
        customer_username: username,
    });
};
```

In another context, I am trying to print the value of **customerInfo** but the value is coming out to be undefined. Any idea on why this could be happening?

AnotherComponent.js

```
   const { customerInfo } = useContext(CustomerContext);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(customerInfo));
```